# $T_1(\vec{v}) = A \vec{v}$ and $T_2(\vec{w}) = A^{\top} \vec{w}$. Prove that $T_1$ is surjective iff $T_2$ is injective.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I could use some help with the following problem:

> Let $T_1: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $T_2: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be such that $T_1(\vec{v}) = A \vec{v}$ and $T_2(\vec{w}) = A^{\top} \vec{w}$ for all $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $\vec{w} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, for some $n \times m$ matrix $A$. Prove that $T_1$ is surjective if and only if $T_2$ is injective.

My attempt:
$\implies$ direction: Suppose $T_2$ is injective, and let $\vec{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Our goal is to show that there exists some $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $T_1(\vec{x}) = \vec{y}$, i.e. $A \vec{x} = \vec{y}$. I know that $T_2$ being injective means that $T_2(\vec{w}_1) = T_2(\vec{w}_2) \implies \vec{w}_1 = \vec{w}_2$, from which it follows that $T_2(\vec{w}) = \vec{0} \iff \vec{w} = 0$ for all $\vec{w} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. But I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

$\impliedby$ direction: Suppose $T_1$ is surjective and that $T_2(\vec{w}_1) = T_2(\vec{w}_2)$ for some $\vec{w}_1,\vec{w}_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$, that is, $A^{\top} \vec{w}_1 = A^{\top} \vec{w}_2$. Our goal is to show that $\vec{w}_1 = \vec{w}_2$. Now by the surjectivity of $T_1$, we have $\vec{w}_1 = T_1(\vec{v}_1) = A \vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{w}_2 = T_1(\vec{v}_2) = A \vec{v}_2$ for some $\vec{v}_1, \vec{v}_2 \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Thus, $A^{\top} A \vec{v}_1 = A^{\top} A \vec{v}_2$, which implies $A^{\top} A (\vec{v}_1 - \vec{v}_2) = \vec{0}$. Now it is enough to show that $\vec{v}_1 - \vec{v}_2 = \vec{0}$, but I'm not sure how to show this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There's an identity that practically give this to you: the columnspace of $A$ is the orthogonal complement of the nullspace of $A^\top$ (or $A^*$ in the complex space). Note you can replace $A$ with $A^\top$ to get a dual identity. Also note that the columnspace of $A$ is the range of $T_1$, while the nullspace of $A^\top$ is the kernel of $T_2$. I would try proving this identity if you haven't seen it before (heads up: it's easy elementary to show the spaces are orthogonal, but you'll also need a dimension theorem to show they are complements), and use it to prove this exercise.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks! This was helpful. I just need to review a lot of basic concepts as it's been a while since I took linear algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution using the Rank-Nullity Theorem:

\begin{align*}
 T_1: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n \text{ is surjective} &\iff \text{rank}(A) = n \\[5pt]
&\iff \text{rank}(A^{T}) = n  && (\text{Since } \text{rank}(A) = \text{rank}(A^T)) \\[5pt]
&\iff \text{nullity}(A^T) = 0   && (\text{Rank-Nullity Theorem}) \\[5pt]
&\iff T_2: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m \text{ is injective}. 
\end{align*}

When I first posted the question I mistakenly wrote that $A$ was an $m \times n$ matrix, which caused me some confusion. $A$ is in fact $n \times m$, which means $A^T$ is $m \times n$. Then by the Rank-Nullity Theorem, $\text{rank}(A^T) + \text{nullity}(A^T) = \#$ of columns of $A^T = n$. Hence why $\text{rank}(A^T) = n$ implies that $\text{nullity}(A^T) = 0$.